# Building load bearing wall partition to hang TV

Tags: drywall, studs, load-bearing, partition

I am planning to build the partition which will used for hanging TV which is 75inch that might weight around 35 kg  to 45 kg. I was thinking to attach piece of wood in between the ceiling joist which is then nailed to the partition wall below to make load bearing. So I was wondering attaching extra stud between joist and then to new partition wall for hanging tv will hinder the structural integrity of the house?

Edited:
[image]

[image]

@jim and toxicantidote, above is the picture with red mark that denotes the stud that I am planning to attach with nail. In first picture side stud will be attach to the brickwall, floor stud (already installed) and above to new stud (second picture) through the ceiling plasterboard.

Comment: One does not need a "load bearing wall" to hang a TV, even the heaviest TV that anyone would have. Do you have a truss roof in which the bottom cords of the trusses serve as ceiling joists? If you have a truss roof, you would not want to connect a partition wall to the trusses in the way you describe because the bottom cords of the trusses move up and down in response to temperature changes. If you do not have trusses, you could just attach a top plate to the ceiling joists. You need to describe the current structure and where you want to hang this TV in relation to the current walls.

Comment: A diagram of the proposed setup would help immensely.

Comment: I got some dumb thing off Amazon that can retract the TV up to the ceiling when it's not in use. It just hangs down all the time anyway. Do you really want that wall crowding the entry to your house like that? I wouldn't want a wall right there. I just searched for `TV ceiling mount` and all sorts of stuff came up. Ah, dang. I didn't see the bottom plate cut in already.

Comment: Your premise is flawed: Attaching blocking between two joists then attaching the top plate of a new wall does _not_ make that wall load bearing. It just keeps the new wall from wobbling.

Comment: Additionally, attaching the wall to the entry wall will certainly keep that end from wobbling, and 2 nails through the top plate into the last two joists above (farthest from the entry wall) will keep the other end from wobbling. Job done.

Comment: I see your biggest problem being the crown molding.

Comment: @Huesmann can you explain how crown molding could create the problem?

Comment: @SunilShrestha well, your wall is going to either have to have crown molding added to it, or you're going to end the crown molding where it currently ends on the brick wall and it won't continue to your new wall, which will look dumb.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a new wall making your house weaker.

40kG is not a large load and it will mostly be pressing on the bottom plate, it's not like this is an "exercise" pole.

Generally for partition walls (which this is) the top plate is connected horizontally to the nearest truss to stop it from flapping sideways, but still allowing some vertical freedom.  You can install the top plate below the ceiling drywall and just nail through it to the connecting wood.

Comment: does the connecting wood  between truss need to be perpendicular to the new wall or same direction would be fine like in the picture I have shown.

Comment: Can I screw directly top plate of new wall to the truss without adding connecting stud inside the roof so that I don't have to go inside the roof